# Is it possible to use std::vector<std::any> vec; Which will result in heterogeneous datatypes

Tags: c++, c++17

Is it possible to define `std::vector<std::any> vec`.

https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/06/any.html#message-passing 
// you can use it in a container:

```
std::map<std::string, std::any> m;
m["integer"] = 10;
m["string"] = std::string("Hello World");
m["float"] = 1.0f;
std::vector<std::any> vec;
```

Can we have something like

```
class a
{
   int val;
}

class b
{
   float val;
}

vec.emplaceback(a);
vec.emplaceback(b);
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Yes, but in you'r case it's better to use classic polymorphism. e.g. `class base { base(const base&) = delete; base& operator=(const base&) = delete; public: virtual ~base() noexcept = default; }; class a: public base { ... masked_type type() {return type_} ... }; class b: public base { ... }; .... std::vector< std::shared_ptr<base> > vec; vec.emplace_back( std::make_shared( ... ) ); vec.emplace_back( std::make_shared( ... ) );` so that you can be sure only messages in the container, std::any can hold everything.

Comment: I would be cautious to use a `std::vector<any>` for any reasonably sized container. Iteration over it is very slow due to all the runtime checking.  If you can enumerate your types, I recommend using a `variant` and a visitor pattern. If you cannot, there is the possibility of polymorphism like above, and depending on your use case something like Sean Parent's "runtime polymorphism". If you don't care about the types until you need to iterate (and you know which types to iterate over), we can cheat a little bit and use a "heterogeneous container" (google for true heterogeneous container)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

`std::any` is just a type-safe wrapper around a `void*`, with value semantics.

See your code copy-paste-corrected in a [live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b481d1238a45872d).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have an example that I use to convert a variadic template pack to runtime. It's not optimized in the fact that it does copies of the passed arguments and it erases the vector on each pass, but it demonstrates the idea (in reality, you would use a `for` loop and `std::ref<>`):

```
template<typename ... many>
void safe_printf(const char *s, many ... args)
{   
    using namespace std;
    vector<any> a = {args ...};

    while (*s) {
        if (*s == '%') {
            if (*(s + 1) == '%') {
                ++s;
            }
            else {

                if (a.empty())
                    throw std::logic_error("Fewer arguments provided to printf");

                if (a[0].type() == typeid(string)) cout << any_cast<string>(a[0]);
                if (a[0].type() == typeid(int)) cout << any_cast<int>(a[0]);
                if (a[0].type() == typeid(double)) cout << any_cast<double>(a[0]);

                a.erase(a.begin());
                s++;
            }
        }
        cout << *s++;
    }
}

int main()
{
 safe_printf("Hello % how are you today? I have % eggs and your height is %","Jack"s, 32,5.7);
 // Hello Jack how are you today? I have 32 eggs and your height is 5.7
}
```

The idea of course is that `std::any` is not a template itself, but it relies on run time checks to see what sort of pointer it stores.